# How do I query multiple temporal tables from Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have multiple temporal tables in my database and I would like to write a query that joins these tables together, but also uses data *as of* a certain date.

I created the following extension method to assist in getting the data as of a date:

```
public static IQueryable<T> AsOf<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet, DateTime? asOfDateTime) where T : class
{
    if (dbSet == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dbSet));
    return asOfDateTime.HasValue
        ? dbSet.FromSql($"SELECT * FROM dbo.[{typeof(T).Name}] FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF {{0}}", asOfDateTime)
        : dbSet;
}
```

This works if it's a simple query like:

```
from entity in context.Entities.AsOf(asOfDateTime)
select new Entity
{
    entity.Name
    ...
```

However, if I try to join tables together like this...

```
from entity in context.Entities.AsOf(asOfDateTime)
select new Entity
{
    entity.Name,
    MyProperties = from myProperty in context.MyProperties.AsOf(asOfDateTime)
                 where myProperty.EntityId == entity.EntityId
                 select new MyProperty
                 {
                     ...
```

Then I start getting an error such as

`` Expression of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable1[MyProperty]'
cannot be used for parameter of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet1[MyProperty]'
of method 'System.Linq.IQueryable1[MyProperty] AsOf[MyProperty](Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet1[MyProperty], System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])'
Parameter name: arg0 ``

Is it possible to query multiple temporal tables from Entity Framework Core? What would the syntax be?

Comment: I can't speak to this well enough to give it as an answer at the moment, but my guess is it's having trouble translating that into a Sql query. You may need to run the sub queries individually as LinqToSql, then join them together afterwards. That would avoid the restriction that LinqToSql must be translatable to standard Sql.

Comment: You could very well be having a problem here "where myProperty.EntityId == entity.EntityId". See this github issue thread for an explanation. https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/7917

Comment: @adam0101, where you able to query multiple temporal tables?

Comment: @Alvykun, unfortunately no. I ended up using stored procedures instead. One thing that did help me was that I made sql functions for each table that encapsulated the as-of logic so that the queries where easy to write and follow.

Comment: @adam0101, Ok! Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Alvykun, I just happened to run into this today, it might help you: https://github.com/Adam-Langley/efcore-temporal-query

Comment: @adam0101, It does the trick! However, i am using EF 2.2 and that library is only compatible with EF 3.1 (ToT)

Comment: @Alvykun, Search for the word "temporal" on this page and you should find one that works for you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/